# How can I prevent that a LCL defined focused empty ListBox implementing some kind of search field

Tags: freepascal, lazarus

I'm working with

- FreePascal 3.2.0,
- Lazarus 2.0.12,
- GTK2 GUI backend
- under Ubuntu Linux 18.04.

I have a strange behavior of a TListBox component.

1. When I focus a empty ListBox by clicking (SetFocus) and
2. press the [space] key,
   some kind of Edit or SearchField appears (..see image below).
3. The field vanishes after a short period (3 s).

How can I switch off this *"feature"*.

[image]

My current work around is to use a handler for the onEnter event to take away the ListBox focus (full code example see below).

```pascal
procedure TFrmMain.lbxTestEnter(Sender: TObject);
    begin
      if mUseWorkAround then begin
         if LbxTest.Items.Count = 0 then begin
            PnlButton.SetFocus;
            exit;
         end;
      end;
    end;
```

I'm not sure if this is the right way.

**Full Code Example:**

```pascal
unit UFrmTestListBox;

{$mode objfpc}{$H+}

interface

uses
  Classes, SysUtils, Forms, Controls, Graphics, Dialogs, ExtCtrls,
  StdCtrls;

const

  PNL_MESSAGE = 'WORK AROUND IS %sACTIVE! ';

type

  { TFrmMain }

  TFrmMain = class(TForm)
    BtnToggle: TButton;
    GbxList:   TGroupBox;
    GbxLog:    TGroupBox;
    LbxTest:   TListBox;
    MmLog:     TMemo;
    PnlButton: TPanel;
    SplMain:   TSplitter;
    procedure  BtnToggleClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure  FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure lbxTestEnter(Sender: TObject);
  private
    mUseWorkAround: Boolean;
    mCounter: Integer;
    procedure OutLn(S:String);
  public

  end;

var
  FrmMain: TFrmMain;

implementation

{$R *.lfm}

procedure TFrmMain.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  mUseWorkAround:= false;
  mCounter := 0;
  PnlButton.Caption:=Format(PNL_MESSAGE,['NOT ']);
end;

procedure TFrmMain.lbxTestEnter(Sender: TObject);
begin
  inc(mCounter);
  OutLn('');
  OutLn(Format('--- %d -----------------------', [mCounter]));
  OutLn('ListBox onEnter event');
  if mUseWorkAround then begin
     OutLn('Work around is active!');
     if LbxTest.Items.Count = 0 then begin
        OutLn('ListBox is empty, change focus to the button panel.');
        PnlButton.SetFocus;
        exit;
     end;
  end else begin
    OutLn('Work around NOT active!');
    OutLn('ListBox is empty, press [SPACE] & EditField appears.')
  end;
end;

procedure TFrmMain.BtnToggleClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  mUseWorkAround:=not mUseWorkAround;
  if mUseWorkAround then
    PnlButton.Caption:=Format(PNL_MESSAGE,[''])
  else
    PnlButton.Caption:=Format(PNL_MESSAGE,['NOT ']);
end;

procedure TFrmMain.OutLn(S:String);
begin
     MmLog.Lines.BeginUpdate;
     MmLog.Lines.Append(S);
     MmLog.Lines.EndUpdate;
     MmLog.SelStart := Length(MmLog.Lines.Text);
end;

end.
```

Comment: This q requires a proper [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), not just a screenshot and the scrap of code you have now, because a standard TListBox dropped onto an empty form certainly does not behave in the way you describe.  Without an mre, the q will likely be closed.

Comment: @Martyn 
1. I adopted the question, but I'm not quite sure how to provide full code examples, including the project and form designer data in this forum.
2. The program behaves like it behaves...

Comment: This seems to be a pecularity of gtk2 (also gtk3 has it, but qt5 doesn't). Any key press triggers a incremental search. This happens also on qt or win, but gtk seems to be the only widgetset which displays the pressed keys in its own window - which is quite cute BTW because you can edit the search phrase this way. AFAIK there is no way to switch off this feature. If you absolutely do not want to see the popping up search window you could write an OnKeyDown handler for the listbox which catches and kills all key presses except for VK_UP, VK_DOWN, VK_HOME, VK_END (maybe some more...)

Comment: @wp_1233996 Thank you for the detailed analysis. I've tried the key handler approach but, the popup event is triggered before the key handler is reached. I've tested onKeyDown, onKeyPress and onKeyUp. The only solution that works for me is to remove the Focus in the onEnter context from the ListBox.  May this will be a problem in a Drag and Drop schema.

Comment: Just tested again: yes it is working. Did you set the Key parameter to 0 for the key presses to be killed? The following code kills the space key press: 

uses
  LCLType;

procedure TForm1.ListBox1KeyDown(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word;
  Shift: TShiftState);
begin
  if (Key = VK_SPACE) then
    Key := 0;
end;

Comment: No I simply leave the event. you suggest to set the Key to zero. BTW, can we change to the answer format? 

    procedure TFrmMain.lbxTestKeyDown(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word;
      Shift: TShiftState);
    begin
      inc(mEvtCounter);
      if (LbxTest.Items.Count = 0) then exit;
     OutLn(IntToStr(mEvtCounter)+': Key code '+IntToHex(Key,2)+' [hex] down', Sender);
   end;

Comment: You MUST set the Key to zero, otherwise it will still be handled by the following events OnKeyUp and OnKeyPress.